# SUM in an ascending order, breaking by limit of sum

Tags: sql, oracle, row

I'm trying to SUM hours with SQL, but I can't just sum it. The sum needs to be in an ascending order, and when it gets to the limit of boundary, it continues the summing in another column or row.

The data I have is like this:

```
Employee_Id |    Date     | Overtime_Day | Overtime_Night
48          |  05/03/2014 |   3 hours    |   4 hours
48          |  05/04/2014 |   9 hours    |   1 hours
48          |  05/10/2014 |   1 hours    |   1 hours
48          |  05/20/2014 |   9 hours    |   4 hours
            |             |= 22 hours    | = 10 hours
```

The boundaries for the SUM is like this:

```
Overtime (Day+Night) 50%: from 0 to 15
Overtime (Day+Night) 100%: > 15
```

But I need to know too if it's day hour or night hour.

```
Overtime 50% is all hours from 0 to 15, no matter if it's day or night:
3 hours [05/03/2014] [Day]
4 hours [05/03/2014] [Night]
8 hours [05/04/2014] [Day] (2 hours is left for this day, left hours and next hours will be 100%)
Overtime 100% is all hours above 15:
1 hours [05/04/2014] [Day]
1 hours [05/04/2014] [Night]
1 hours [05/10/2014] [Day]
1 hours [05/10/2014] [Night]
9 hours [05/20/2014] [Day]
4 hours [05/20/2014] [Night]
```

Then I have:

```
Overtime 50% day: 11 hrs
Overtime 50% night: 4 hrs
Overtime 100% day: 11 hrs
Overtime 100% night: 6 hrs
```

Result I want

```
Employee_Id | Overtime_Day_50% | Overtime_Night_50% | Overtime_Day_100% | Overtime_Night_100% 
48          |   11 hours       |   4 hours          |   11 hrs          |    6 hrs
```

Or

```
Employee_Id |       Type           |   Hours    
48          |  Overtime_Day_50%    |   11 hours
48          |  Overtime_Night_50%  |   4 hours
48          |  Overtime_Day_100%   |   11 hours
48          |  Overtime_Night_100% |   6 hours
```

(It doesn't matter row-way or column-way)

Sorry if I didn't make myself clear and I really don't know if it's possible to accomplish this calculation with only SQL.

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks!

---

Edit

I have this SELECT which I can get all Overtime 50% and all Overtime 100%, but with this I can't separate what is day and what is night hour.

```
WITH DATA AS (           
SELECT 48 AS EMPLOYEE_ID, '05/03/2014' AS "DATE", 3 AS OVERTIME_DAY, 4 AS OVERTIME_NIGHT FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 48 AS EMPLOYEE_ID, '05/04/2014' AS "DATE", 9 AS OVERTIME_DAY, 1 AS OVERTIME_NIGHT FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 48 AS EMPLOYEE_ID, '05/10/2014' AS "DATE", 1 AS OVERTIME_DAY, 1 AS OVERTIME_NIGHT FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 48 AS EMPLOYEE_ID, '05/20/2014' AS "DATE", 9 AS OVERTIME_DAY, 4 AS OVERTIME_NIGHT FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    CASE WHEN SUM(OVERTIME_DAY + OVERTIME_NIGHT) >= 15 THEN
      15
    ELSE
      SUM(OVERTIME_DAY + OVERTIME_NIGHT)
    END AS OVERTIME_50,

    GREATEST(0,SUM(OVERTIME_DAY + OVERTIME_NIGHT) - 15) AS OVERTIME_100

FROM DATA
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Result:

```
Employeed_Id   |   OVERTIME_50    |   OVERTIME_100
    48         |        15        |         17
```

Comment: is it SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL or some other RDBMS?

Comment: Could you post the SQLyou are currently using?

Comment: In addition to the comments above, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: question about third code block: comment on line 4 is not clear. 8+4+3 = 15, where 2 hours are comming from? 5/03 and 5/04 are summed up together? date is not important at all?

Comment: Actually I am using Oracle, but I tagged other RDBMS in my question just to received any ideas from all of them, so I can later convert it to oracle.

Comment: vav, if you check the day 05/03 from the data, i have a total of 10 hours of overtime for this day. But only 8 hours more is enough to break the limit of the overtime 50%, so the left 2 hours will be thrown into overtime 100%.

Comment: DalmTo, I edited my question with the SQL I have until now. I can only separate what is 50% or 100%, but I can't separate what is day or night with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the data in the same format of the original, i.e. adding new columns instead of new rows, we can get

```
With D AS (
  Select Employee_Id, "Date", Overtime_Day, Overtime_Night
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) 
         OVER (ORDER BY "Date") - Overtime_Night Total_Day
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) 
         OVER (ORDER BY "Date") Total_Night
  From   Data
)
SELECT Employee_Id
     , SUM(Case When Total_Day < 15 Then Overtime_Day
                When Total_Day < 15 + Overtime_Day 
                  Then Overtime_Day - (Total_Day - 15)
                Else 0 
           END) Overtime_Day_50
     , SUM(Case When Total_Night < 15 Then Overtime_Night 
                When Total_Night < 15 + Overtime_Night 
                  Then Overtime_Night - (Total_Night - 15)
                Else 0 
           END) Overtime_Night_50
     , SUM(Case When Total_Day < 15 Then 0
            When Total_Day < 15 + Overtime_Day Then Total_Day - 15
            When Total_Day > 15 Then Overtime_Day
       END) Overtime_Day_100
     , SUM(Case When Total_Night < 15 Then 0
            When Total_Night < 15 + Overtime_Night Then Total_Night - 15
            When Total_Night > 15 Then Overtime_Night
       END) Overtime_Night_100
FROM   D
GROUP BY Employee_Id
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a297/24)</kbd>

In the CTE it's calculated the rolling total for the overtime for the day and the night, in the formula for the total overtime for the day is subtracted `Overtime_Night` to get the sum of the previous overtime and the `Overtime_Day` of the current row.
In the main query the `CASE` use a 'simple' algorithm to calculate values:

- if the total hour are less then 15, get the current hour
- if the total hour is more then 15 but within the buffer of current hour get the part of current hour that is valid
- otherwise it's not at 50%

the part for the 100% work the opposite

- if the total hour are less then 15, we are not at 100%
- if the total hour is more then 15 but within the buffer of current hour get the part that exceed 15
- otherwise it's all at 100%

---

To have a more generic case, as in a comment by the OP it's possible to create other groups like

```
     , SUM(Case When Total_Day < %bStart% Then 0
                When Total_Day < %bStart% + Overtime_Day Then Total_Day - %bStart%
                When Total_Day < %bEnd% And Total_Day > %bStart% Then Overtime_Day
                When Total_Day < %bEnd% + Overtime_Day Then Overtime_Day - (Total_Day - %bEnd%)
                Else 0 
           END) Overtime_Day_60
     , SUM(Case When Total_Night < %bStart% Then 0
                When Total_Night < %bStart% + Overtime_Night Then Total_Night - %bStart%
                When Total_Night < %bEnd% And Total_Night > %bStart% Then Overtime_Night
                When Total_Night < %bEnd% + Overtime_Night Then Overtime_Night - (Total_Night - %bStart%)
                Else 0 
           END) Overtime_Night_60
```

with `%bStart%` and `%bEnd%` as the start and end values of the blocks, but it will not be very flexible, with more than two block a different approach is better, and it will also allow to remove the magic numbers from the query to move them in a table

```
With D AS (
  SELECT Employee_Id, "Date", Overtime_Day, Overtime_Night
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) OVER (ORDER BY "Date") 
       - (Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) Total_Begin
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) OVER (ORDER BY "Date")
       - Overtime_Night Total_Day
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) OVER (ORDER BY "Date") Total_Night
  FROM   Data
), Block AS (
  SELECT 1 ID, 'Overtime_50' Name, 0 bStart, 15 bEnd FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Overtime_60', 15, 20 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'Overtime_100', 20, 999 FROM DUAL
)
  SELECT Employee_Id
       , block.Name
       , SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Begin < bStart AND Total_Day > bStart THEN Total_Day - bStart
                  WHEN Total_Day < bStart THEN 0
                  WHEN Total_Day <= bEnd THEN OverTime_Day
                  WHEN Total_Begin < bEnd AND Total_Day > bEnd THEN bEnd - Total_Begin
             END) Overtime_Day
       , SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Day >= bStart AND Total_Night < bEnd THEN Overtime_Night
                  WHEN Total_Begin < bEnd AND Total_Day > bEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Total_Day > bStart AND Total_Night > bEnd THEN bEnd - Total_Day
                  WHEN Total_Day < bStart AND Total_Night > bStart THEN Total_Night - bStart
             END) Overtime_Night
  FROM   D
         INNER JOIN Block ON
               (Total_Begin < bStart AND Total_Night > bStart)
            OR (Total_Begin >= bStart AND Total_Begin < bEnd)
GROUP BY Employee_Id, block.Name, block.ID
ORDER BY block.ID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/249f10/22)</kbd> with the data changed to have a block change at both day and night.

All the condition are inequalities to check the boundaries.

The output format is

```
Employee_Id | Name         | Overtime_Day | Overtime_Night
         48 | Overtime_50  |           11 |              4
         48 | Overtime_60  |            2 |              3
         48 | Overtime_100 |            9 |              5
```

a little different from the original OP output request, but from here getting to those is not difficult, if necessary.

If you want in one row & multiple column format, just use the `PIVOT` operator.

```
    With D AS (
  SELECT Employee_Id, "Date", Overtime_Day, Overtime_Night
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) OVER (ORDER BY "Date") 
       - (Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) Total_Begin
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) OVER (ORDER BY "Date")
       - Overtime_Night Total_Day
       , SUM(Overtime_Day + Overtime_Night) OVER (ORDER BY "Date") Total_Night
  FROM   Data
), Block AS (
  SELECT 1 ID, 'Overtime_50' Name, 0 bStart, 15 bEnd FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Overtime_60', 15, 20 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'Overtime_100', 20, 999 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Employee_Id
       , block.Name
       , SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Begin < bStart AND Total_Day > bStart THEN Total_Day - bStart
                  WHEN Total_Day < bStart THEN 0
                  WHEN Total_Day <= bEnd THEN OverTime_Day
                  WHEN Total_Begin < bEnd AND Total_Day > bEnd THEN bEnd - Total_Begin
             END) Overtime_Day
       , SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Day >= bStart AND Total_Night < bEnd THEN Overtime_Night
                  WHEN Total_Begin < bEnd AND Total_Day > bEnd THEN 0
                  WHEN Total_Day > bStart AND Total_Night > bEnd THEN bEnd - Total_Day
                  WHEN Total_Day < bStart AND Total_Night > bStart THEN Total_Night - bStart
             END) Overtime_Night
    FROM   D
         INNER JOIN Block ON
               (Total_Begin < bStart AND Total_Night > bStart)
            OR (Total_Begin >= bStart AND Total_Begin < bEnd)
    GROUP BY Employee_Id, block.Name, block.ID
    ORDER BY block.ID
)PIVOT (SUM(OVERTIME_DAY) AS Day, SUM(OVERTIME_NIGHT) AS Night FOR (Name) in ('Overtime_50' as Overtime_50,'Overtime_60' as Overtime_60,'Overtime_100' as Overtime_100))
```

The output format is

```
Employee_Id | Overtime_50_Day | Overtime_50_Night | Overtime_60_Day | Overtime_60_Night | Overtime_100_Day | Overtime_100_Night
         48 |              11 |                4  |               2 |                 3 |                9 |                  5
```

Comment: Hey Serpiton, thank you for your response :) it worked like a charm. Yet I'm still analyzing your logic and I have a question. In this code it always "prioritizes" the day hours (as if the day hours had come first than the night hours). If I just remove the subtraction of "Overtime_Night" in Total_Day and put a subtraction of "Overtime_Day" in Total_Night I would get the night prioritized?

Comment: I get it. Thank you. Still I'm trying to do some changes, like add another overtime range (60%) between the two ranges but I'm having some problems with it. Can you give me a hand in this change? The new ranges would be: Overtime 50%: from 0 to 15, Overtime 60%: from 16 to 20, Overtime 100%: > 20. I appreciate your help, man! I'll keep with my tries.

Comment: This is definitely better than what I was trying. Thank you again. I've made a little change just to swap row to column, because I need them in one row & multiple column format. So I've edited your comment with this approach, hope u don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

IF the overtime is computed regardless of day OR night, why NOT just pre-aggregate totals per group (day/night) and grand total vs on a per-day basis.  Pay would be done at the end of a pay period anyhow.  Would something like...

```
SELECT
      PreQry.*,
      PreQry.TotalHours,
      CASE when PreQry.TotalHours <= 15 
         then PreQry.TotalHours
         ELSE 15 end as OTAt50Pcnt,
      CASE when PreQry.TotalHours <= 15 
         then 0
         ELSE PreQry.TotalHours - 15 end as OTAt100Pcnt
   from
      ( select 
              tc.Employee_ID,
              SUM( tc.overtime_day + tc.overtime_night ) as totalHours,
              SUM( tc.overtime_day ) as totalOTDay,
              SUM( tc.overtime_night ) as totalOTNight
           from
              TimeCards tc
           group by
              tc.Employee_ID ) PreQry
```

This would produce something along the lines of

```
Employee_Id  TotalHours   Total Day O/T   Total Night O/T   O/T at 50%   O/T at 100% 
48           32           22 hours        10 hours          15 hrs       17 hrs
```

I think this is a more doable solution, but just offering as an alternative to a per-day roll-up with Oracle.  I'm sure someone with more in-depth experience might be able to offer more exact to your request though.

Comment: I could use this If I did not need to separate what is day hour and what is night hour from both O/T 50% and O/T 100%. By manually summing in an ascending order from the data, I know the values are the following: Overtime 50% day: 11 hrs, Overtime 50% night: 4 hrs, Overtime 100% day: 11 hrs and Overtime 100% night: 6 hrs. But I can't figure out yet how to put this in logic in this select. Thank you for your answer :)